# Ошибка module 'rsa' has no attribute 'newkeys' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, python-3.x, rsa

Код:

```
import rsa

#Боб формирует публичный и секретный ключ

(bob_pub, bob_priv) = rsa.newkeys(512)

#Алиса формирует сообщение Бобу и кодирует его в UTF8, 
#поскольку RSA работает только с байтами
message = 'hello Bob!'.encode('utf8')

#Алиса шифрует сообщение публичным ключом Боба
crypto = rsa.encrypt(message, bob_pub)

#Боб расшифровывает сообщение своим секретным ключом
message = rsa.decrypt(crypto, bob_priv)
print(message.decode('utf8'))
```

Устанавливал модуль как сказано в документации: `pip install rsa`

Использую Python 3.9.

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому, что ваш файл очевидно называется `rsa.py`, значит, ищется *ваша* функция `newkeys()`, а в вашем файле такой нет.

Переименуйте ваш файл.